# How do I do this in Java, C#, or Python?

Tags: java, c#, python

I was given a code challenge that I failed on (rather badly) for a junior dev job and its been going through my mind over and over.

The question was:
assume N is of length 1-100. The task is to return N as a string.

For example if N = 5 then return "+-+-+"
or if N is 3 then retun "+-+"

N was assigned to type Int at the start of the algorithm.

I tried using Java but failing the test I don't see how showing my code will help. All im after is a solution so I can see how it is done and learn from it.

I may use the following languages: Java, Python, C#.

Comment: This question is too broad in its current form. Please clarify: _which language_ would you/did you try to answer in? What was your attempt? How was the result not what you wanted?

Comment: I tried using java. my attempt was to use a for loop to N.length() similar to the asnwer given but my return type was different.

Comment: `N.legth()` would be the problem as an `int` would not have a `length` method in any language.

Comment: You mean 'allowed,' not 'aloud.'

Answer (score 3):

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    private static string StringN(int N)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            builder.Append(i%2 == 0 ? "+" : "-");
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(StringN(i));
        }
    }
}
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1ldegc) is a fiddle. C# is used in the above code.

Comment: Thank you. This has bugged me for some time.

Comment: @hoot, you are welcome. (y)

Answer (score 3):

Java 11+

```
public static String getStringFromN(int n) {
    return String.format("%s%s", "+-".repeat(n / 2), n % 2 == 1 ? "+" : "");
}
```

Comment: If you repeat `n` times a string with 2 characters, you can safely divide it in two, and be sure both sides have the same size. It's a multiple of two after the first operation. Essentially removing the same operation from both sides of the equation.

Comment: Or even, `return "+-".repeat(50).substring(0, n);`

Answer (score 3):

Multiply the string `+-` `n` times. Return the first `n` characters from that string.

### In Python

```py
>>> def f(n):
...     template = '+-'
...     string = template * n
...     return string[:n]
... 
>>> f(5)
'+-+-+'
>>> f(3)
'+-+'
>>>
```

Or, in one line `f = lambda n: ('+-' * n)[:n]`.

### In C Sharp

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    private static string f(int n)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            builder.Append("+-");

        return builder.ToString().Substring(n);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(f(3));
        Console.WriteLine(f(5));
    }
}
```

And a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UhLpFq).

Comment: One line in C# `new string(Enumerable.Range(0,n).Select(x => x%2 == 0 ? '+' : '-').ToArray())`

Comment: @juharr Awesome. Edit the answer to add that. But I don't like that modulos operator at all, is totally unnecessary and together with a ternary operator is confusing. You can just do an enumerable `2 * n` to make it a multiple of 2 and be safely divisible by 2. Much simpler to understand.

Answer (score 2):

```
n = int(input("Enter N:"))

for i in range(0,n):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print("+", end =""),
    else:
        print("-",  end =""),
```

Here is a solution in python

Comment: You can simply multiply the string `+-` `n` times. And return `n` characters from the resulting string. Python supports operator overloading for that situation. I've posted an answer with that solution.

Answer (score 1):

A (non-condensed) version in Java:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int N = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      if(i % 2 == 0)
        builder.append("+");
      else
        builder.append("-");
    }

    System.out.println("Value: " + N);
    System.out.println(builder.toString());
  }
```